# DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to plot y data frame but I had an error like below. Any suggestions?

```
g1= sns.scatterplot( x= "events", y= "ways" , data = x2)
```

Output message

> DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get

Comment: you can't use seaborn with spark dataframes. Convert to pandas first, e.g. `data = x2.toPandas()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seaborn expects pandas dataframes and not spark dataframes. Change your code to:

```
g1= sns.scatterplot( x= "events", y= "ways" , data = x2.toPandas())
```

and it should work.